# Why can't our Sunni brothers agree to the curse of Muawiya ibn Abu Sufyan

Tags: history, shia-sunni, sahaba, curse

> "And whoever kills a believer intentionally, his recompense shall be
>   hell, he shall abide therein and God’s wrath shall be on him and his
>   curse, and is prepared for him a great torment”
>
> *`(Surah Nisa:93)`.*

Muawiyah ibn Abu Sufyan killed respectively ordered the killing of Sahabah, e.g. Amr bin al-Hamiq, Malik bin Ashthar, Hujr bin Adbar, only for the reason that they were followers of Ali ibn Abi Talib.

> “Ayesha said: ‘Mu’awiya you killed Hujr and his associates, By Allah! The Prophet told me ‘In the ditch of Adra seven men will be killed, due to this all the skies and Allah will be upset”.

A contemporary Hanafi scholar, Mufti Ghulam Rasul, wrote in his book *Subeh al-Sadiq*, p.93/94 , that Hujr and his companions were killed because they refused to curse Ali ibn Abi Talib.

> `Tarikh ibn Asakir, V.12, p.227`

Additionally, he instigated the poisoning of the first grandson of the Holy Prophet, Hassan ibn Ali.

> > “Sho’ubi states that Mu’awiya sent a message to Jada bint al-Ash’ath bin al Qays that if you poison Hasan then I shall marry you to Yazeed
> >     and in addition to this I shall give 100,000 dirhams. When Hasan was
> >     martyred Judh sent a message to Mu’awiya asking that he fulfil his
> >     side of the deal. Mu’awiya sent the money but said “I reject that
> >     matter of Yazeed since I want him to remain alive, had this matter not
> >     occurred then I would have married you to Yazeed”.
>
> `Tadkhirat au Khawwas, p. 192`
>
> Mu’awiya reached an agreement with Jada bint al-Ash’ath bin al Qays, namely 100,000 dirhams if she poisons Imam Hasan.

```
Allamah Zamakshari, Rabi’ ul Abrar, V.4, p. 208
```

> Qatada and Abu Bakr bin Hafs stated that Hasan was administered poison, via his wife Ja’da bint Ashath. One group have said that Mu’awiya have sent Ja’da the poison and upon administering this poison, Ja’da was rewarded”.

```
Allamah Ibn Abdul Barr, al-Istiab
```

> “This is commonly known among the people that his wife Ja’da administered poison to him upon the orders of Ameer Mu’awiya.”

```
Maulana Abdur Rahman Jaami, Shawahid un Nubuwwa, p.303
```

Furthermore, he appointed his son Yazid as the ruler over the Muslims after him, who was the pure evil.

In the light of the above mentioned vers of the Holy Qur'an, the Shia seem right to curse him, by asking Allah swt to deprive him of His mercy.  Why can't our Sunni brothers agree to this?

Comment: "he instigated the poisoning of the first grandson of the Holy Prophet "any authentic story from sunni books ? :)

Comment: "only for the reason that they were followers of Ali ibn Abi Talib" this point too need a source :)

Comment: For asking questions about controversial areas you need to quote more evidences!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will provide more evidences, inshallah.

Comment: You should also explain what you mean by "curse" or you're just spreading more misconceptions about Shia! As you see in the answer comments, the answerer thinks of "curse" as mindless profanity or malicious abuse which translates from Arabic "سب" whereas "curse" in your question translates from "لعن" which has a substantial Quranic basis as in [2:161](http://tanzil.net/#2:161), [5:60](http://tanzil.net/#5:60), [5:78](http://tanzil.net/#5:78), [3:87](http://tanzil.net/#3:87) just to quote a few.

Comment: @melbx There are evidences suggesting this idea of his hate towards Ali (p.b.u.h.). For example , the usual friday cursing of Ali in congregational prayers introduced by Muawiya and followed for so many years until the end of Ummayad reign.

Answer (score 7):

> Aisha reported: The Prophet (SAW) said, “Do not abuse the dead, for they have reached what they put forward.”
>
> In another narration, the Prophet said, “When your companion dies, then leave him alone without speaking badly about him.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 1329
>
> ---
>
> Qais ibn Sa’d reported: A funeral passed by the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, and he stood up. It was said to him, “It is a Jew.” The Prophet said, “Was he not a soul?”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 1250, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 961

These Hadiths show us that we should be respectful of those who have passed away. They have earned what was destined for them. By maligning or  cursing them, we may be earning sins for we may be unknown of the truth.

In another Hadith, the Messenger of Allah (SAW) says:

> “Blessed is the man who speaks good and is triumphant; or keeps silent in the face of evil and is secure”

The truth about the incident between Muawiyah ibn Abu Sufyan  and the family of Prophet (SAW) is known to Allah. He will deal with him in a way that suit His Majestic Justice.

We as an Ummah should be more concerned about our deeds and how we can work together to unite our Ummah and promote Islam.

Salaam!

Comment: The hadiths you quoted seem to be about assuming good faith about average Muslims or people who are not known to be corrupt or big time criminal. But what if we could establish this with certainty (i.e. using historical evidences) that Muawiya was indeed a criminal apostate and responsible for spreading corruption in the Ummah? (Don't take this as offense! That's at least what Shias certainly believe, after all, based on their own evidences).

Comment: Asak! With all due respect brother/sister, the Hadith generalizes the subject to be 'dead'. It does not differentiate whether it is man, woman, child, muslim, non-muslim, sinner or not. The Prophet (SAW) didnt even curse the people of Taif but prayed for their future generations. He even stood up for a Jewish funeral.This is Islam. We were sent as a mercy to this world. If we cant even respect our dead, how will we respect the living? May Allah guide us all to the right path and inspire us to do what is as per Quran & Hadith & grant us all Jannah. Ameen.

Comment: Islam is a mercy to the world but Allah Himself curses (curse as in لعن NOT سب) many groups in the Holy Quran! This means that there exists legitimate cases of curse (again as in لعن). So this is a Quranic clue that apparently qualifies your hadiths apart from the fact that the hadiths themselves really don't seem to be generalizing beyond average people which can include average sinners but not vile and oppressive tyrants whose deeds have affected generations of living after their death!

Comment: Also note لعن only means asking Allah to withhold His grace from somebody, here a person who is believed to have caused great mischief in religion and Ummah and dissociating one's self from whom is key in being in the right Islamic position!

Comment: @Ahmed The Quran curses Abu Laheb . Cursing evil is necessary just as supporting good is necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Because he worshiped God one day and by the way cursing is not our way . 
Whatever happened had happened and we are 1300 year now after him . 
If he is a bad person God Accounts everything .